# superposition of electron polarization

Tags: quantum-spin

Where is this setup shown?  I cannot find it on the internet.  The spin is returned to the original polarization rather than spin-up or down which would be expected from the intermediate superposition from the initial Stern Gerlach device followed by a second device which gives back the original polarization of the electron.  Superposition  of  an electron's random polarization can be recovered from sending the electron through two Stern Gerlach devices which create a spin-up and spin-down superposition which when run through the next device returns the electron to the random spin polarization.

Comment: i hope the question is stated clearly enough.it is my first question and i messed it up.the beginning question should have been asked last.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking. It looks like you want a diagram of sequential Stern-Gerlach devices, but you've said something about a device that returns a random spin polarization. Can you clarify what you mean by editing your post?

Comment: the original polarization of the electron is what is reconstructed from the spin-up and spin-down polarizations which result from the first stern gerlach device.this seems to me to be the principle of quantum computing.the information from the original electron polarization is what can be randomly oriented and then returned to that state by a second stern gerlach device after somehow being coded in the superposition state.you don't think you would be able to do this but apparently this is how q.m. works

Comment: @dirkpetersen You can edit your post. Please, use this to make it clearer.